# ¿Cual seria la diferencia entre interface y metodos? JAVA

Tags: java, interface

Hola buenas entiendo lo que son los métodos(comportamientos que tiene los objetos) e interface(lo que puede hacer una clase/objeto), pero a la hora de crear una interface me confunde y pienso que es lo mismo que los métodos, por ejemplo si tengo una clase abstracta llamada: figura (y ademas podría tener la clase triangulo, cuadrado que extiende de esa) puede tener como método calcularPerimetro y calcularArea , pero también eso podría ser una interface no? Entonces como podría separar (el concepto como para entenderlo mejor) de lo que seria los métodos y por otro lado interfaces.

Comment: Tu pregunta no está para nada definida y confundes casi todos los conceptos. Una interfaz no es *lo que puede hacer una clase/objeto*. Y `calcularPerimetro()` y `calcularArea()` serán siempre métodos, los pongas donde los pongas. El problema es más complejo de lo que parece, porque en las interfaces puede haber por ejemplo métodos estáticos, abstractos y métodos por defecto ([ver aquí](https://www.baeldung.com/java-static-default-methods)), y, si hay una diferencia a entender sería quizá entre interfaz y clase abstracta, así como la cuestión del poliformismo, la herencia múltiple, etc...

Comment: Sugiero que leas [este tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-interfaces), para que tengas de entrada una visión amplia sobre el sentido de las interfaces en Java. Leer sobre las [clases abstractas](https://www.baeldung.com/java-abstract-class) también será importante para entenderlo todo de una forma más completa. Así como tener claros todos los conceptos que son sub-títulos en el primer tutorial de este comentario. El asunto no se entiende en un día, hace falta mucha lectura, practicar con el código y, si tienes un problema concreto, puedes preguntar aquí.

Comment: @computer, hola, podrías decir si las respuestas dadas te fueron útiles y darles un voto positivo si te ayudaron y si lo consideras marcar como aceptada la que más te haya ayudado, gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una **interface** **es un** **tipo de datos abstracto(TDA)** que contiene un conjunto de métodos, los cuales van a ser implementados por las clases que implementen dicha interfaz. Cualquier clase que implemente la interfaz debe implementar todos sus miembros.

En las interfaces se especifica que se debe hacer pero no su implementación. Serán las clases que implementen estas interfaces las que describan la lógica del comportamiento de los métodos.

Una clase puede implementar varias interfaces, y una interfaz a su vez puede heredar de una o varias interfaces. Podría decirse que las interfaces tienen similitud con las clases abstractas y el polimorfismo, aunque ojo, no son lo mismo, una interfaz puede contribuir a un **muy bajo acoplamiento entre clases**, lo cual es ideal para cualquier diseño orientado a objetos.

Un código de ejemplo:

```
//Declaramos nuestra interfaz
public interface ISaludo
{
    public void Saludar();
}

class Asiatico implements ISaludo
{
    public void Saludar()
    {            
        System.out.println("ni hao");
    }
}

class Latino implements ISaludo
{
    public void Saludar()
    {
        System.out.println("Hola");
    }
}
```

Como ves tenemos dos clases: **Asiatico** y **Latino** y ambas implementan la **interfaz ISaludo**.

La **clase Asiatico** da su propia implementación del **método Saludar()** y la **clase Latino** da también su propia implementación de este método.

Comment: @BetaM, lo corregi, es que la palabra implementen la uso mucho en el texto y me parecia redundante en la escritura

Answer (score 4):

Una interfaz no es otra cosa que el mecanismo mediante el cual dos componentes de software (en el ámbito de la programación) pueden comunicarse. Te pongo algunos ejemplos.

1. Un conjunto de servicios WEB (REST o SOAP) sería la interfaz mediante la cual los clientes de un sistema se comunican con el *backend*.
2. El conjunto de todas las clases públicas de una biblioteca de clases constituyen la interfaz de esa biblioteca.
3. El conjunto de todos los métodos públicos de una clase constituyen la interfaz de dicha clase.

Como te puedes dar cuenta, este último ejemplo es donde radica tu duda, ya que el modo en que dos objetos pueden comunicarse entre sí es mediante sus métodos. Esto quiere decir que sí, la interfaz de una clase son todos sus métodos públicos.

Ahora bien, la estructura de programación que en Java se conoce como `interface` ha tomado su nombre precisamente de este concepto. Si te das cuenta, una interfaz (antes de la versión 8 del lenguaje) solo puede contener métodos públicos. Entonces, cuando solo nos interesa abstraer el concepto de *todos los objetos que tienen el mismo comportamiento*, aunque en la práctica sean llevados cabo (implementados) de diferente manera, lo llamamos *extraer o segregar la interfaz* común de estos objetos.

**PD:** A partir de la versión 8 de Java las restricciones que imponía la estructura de programación `interface` han sido flexibilizadas, pero por fines prácticos. A mi en lo particular no me gustan y es precisamente porque han desvirtuado el concepto de interfaz.